# Get HyperLink's NavigateURL property as just "#myhashtag"

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, kentico

I have a user control with a hyperlink control within it.  The application is database driven (it's kentico).

I need set to set the hyperlink's navigateurl property to #section-1.  When I do so, asp.net is converting the user to /myfolder/usercontrols/#section-1. That's not even the URL that was in the browser, and breaks some existing javascript code I'm working with.

How can I easily get the hyperlink's navigateurl property to render as a clean "#section-1"?

Yes, I need a server side control.

If I build the full request URL manually, even with "~/...", asp.net renders it as a **server relative URL**, when I just want a clean href="#section-1".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
HyperLink1.Attributes.Add("href","#section-1")
```

or

```
HyperLink1.Attributes("href") = "#section-1" 'overwrite any existing href
```

Comment: creative!  I didn't think of that

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
hypTheLink.NavigateUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery + "#JumpMark";
```